# Add A Image to the Gallery by Code/Programmatically - Android Eclispe

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-widget, android-gallery

I need help with a certain part of my project. How do you add A photo  of your choice from the SD directory to the Gallery in my app by code/programmatically? I searched on the internet and I find uninformative ways and ways to add multiple images to the gallery when I just want one. Please when explaining it, please explain the information behind the code and the best ways possible so it can make sense. Also please could you show me how to get a photo inside of an directory in the SDcard directory. It's appreciated.

Thank you :)

Comment: If by "add A photo... to the Gallery", you mean "add A photo to the `MediaStore`, so that other apps know that the photo exists", use `MediaScannerConnection` and its static `scanFile()` method.

Comment: No, when I say gallery I mean this: [link](http://www.androidinterview.com/android-gallery-view-example-displaying-a-list-of-images/), I would just like it so my app only knows of its existence..

Comment: The complete and entire point of the `Gallery` widget is to show a horizontally-scrolling roster of images (plural). If you have only one image, just use an `ImageView`, not a `Gallery`.

Comment: The way my app has to be layed out, it has to added one by one at  a time. Thats why I haved asked for a image to be added once, when needed. Its hard to explain but thats is why I need to add a image (at a time).